# Repeatedly match a pattern and return all results

Tags: c#, regex

I have some data:

```
242 B9 Y9 250 F9 258 H9 266 N9 274 T9 18 N25-26
```

This is a list of page numbers and grid locations for a map.  I need a regex that will return all matches in list, so I get something like this:

```
242 B9 Y9
250 F9
258 H9
266 N9
274 T9
18 N25-26
```

Currently I have following:

```
\d*\b .+?(?= \d* )
```

Which in the above example returns every match except the last (18 N25-26)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It didn't work because of the look ahead. After the last part the engine tries to check for digits followed by space ( `(?= \d* )` ) but it sees an end of string.

So add end of string to the look ahead as [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

```
\d*\b .+?(?= \d* |$)
```

- `$` Matches end of string.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/yZ4qD1/1)

Comment: You beat me to it by a couple seconds, so you have my vote :)

Comment: So the | is like an or.  So it's telling regex to look ahead until the next match or the end of the string.  This is perfect, thanks!

Comment: @thorkia You got it. It is called an alternation, I have linked a page which gives good explanation on alternations. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with the rest of the pattern as it currently is, then the simplest fix is to just add the end-of-line as another option in the look-ahead:

```
\d*\b .+?(?= \d* |$)
```

See a [working example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cd*%5Cb%20.%2B%3F(%3F%3D%20%5Cd*%20%7C%24)&i=242%20B9%20Y9%20250%20F9%20258%20H9%20266%20N9%20274%20T9%2018%20N25-26).

Comment: nu11p01n73r beat you to it, but it's correct, so I gave you a vote